# sort two columns in a text file by using java collections framework

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have an input file containing lines like

> ```
> 21,mahesh
> 12,suresh
> 23,rajesh
> 25,lokesh
> ```

By using `ArrayList` I wrote code the code below to handle ascending and descending order

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileRead {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader("D:\\Numbers.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = s.nextLine(); 
            al.add(line);
        }
        Collections.sort(al,Collections.reverseOrder());

        for (String i: al)
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

This yielded the following output

> ```
>  - 25,lokesh
>  - 23,rajesh
>  - 21,mahesh
>  - 12,suresh
> ```

$ In the above code, when I take the entire row as a line by using `Collections.sort()` operation it works.

$ If I take the input like below String column first and integer column next the above code is not working properly it will assign by using String values Alphabetical order,i want to sort the data by using only integer not by String values please help me friends

```
 - mahesh,21
 - suresh,12
 - rajesh,23
 - lokesh,25
```

Comment: Create your own comparator and call Collections.sort() with it

Comment: The first example works by lucky coincidence. Replace 12 with 9 to see why.

Answer (score 2):

First Read the file store it in a Map

```
Map map = new TreeMap();
while(true)
{
 String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
 if(line == null)
 break;
 else {
   String arr[] = line.split(",");
   for(int i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++)
   {
       map.put(arr[i],arr[i+1]);
   }}
}
```

Sort it using Comparator

```
List list = new LinkedList(map.entrySet());
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
  return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue())
                        .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue());
   }
});
```

Finally displat the result

```
Map result = new LinkedHashMap();
for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

For acending switch o1 and o2 in when returning from comparator.

For the second type of input

```
    List list = new LinkedList(map.keySet());
    Collections.sort(list);
    Set set = map.entrySet();
    Map result = new LinkedHashMap();
    for (Iterator it = set.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Comment: this solution has two issues (sorry for the fomatting issues below)
1. The Map will only allow 1 unique key, which means if you have two entries with different values 
     e.g. 
      - 21, mahesh
      - 21, anothermahesh

You will only get the last added value, in this case anothermahesh

2. The sorting will be alphabetical not numeric sorting.  This will show up when you have values such as:

21
212
30`

Comment: when i use this code the output will come based on string alphabetical i want numeric based sorting not alphabetical order

Comment: check the last part of the answer

Answer (score 1):

The following will allow you to parse the information into the appropriate types using a class LineEntry to wrap the data.  It will provide the proper sorting on Integer values instead of treating them as Strings and applying alphabetical ordering.

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileRead {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(FileRead.class.getResourceAsStream("/numbers.txt")));
        s.useDelimiter("[,\\s]");

        ArrayList<LineEntry> lineEntryList = new ArrayList<LineEntry>();
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            int amount = s.nextInt();
            String value = s.next();
            LineEntry lineEntry = new LineEntry(value, amount);
            lineEntryList.add(lineEntry);
        }
        Collections.sort(lineEntryList, Collections.reverseOrder());

        for (LineEntry i : lineEntryList) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }

    public static class LineEntry implements Comparable<LineEntry>{

        private String value;
        private Integer amount;

        public LineEntry(String value, Integer amount) {
            this.value = value;
            this.amount = amount;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public Integer getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }

        public void setAmount(Integer amount) {
            this.amount = amount;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "LineEntry{" + "value=" + value + ", amount=" + amount + '}';
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(LineEntry o) {
            int compareTo = o.getAmount().compareTo(amount);
            if (compareTo == 0) {
                compareTo = o.getValue().compareTo(value);
            }
            return compareTo;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to create a different class which contains data in each line seperated by comma as variables of that class so that in future if you have multiple columns data in the same line then the code can be scalable and also you can create custom comparators based on your sort condition:-

```
public class FileRead {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader("E:\\Numbers.txt"));        
        List<FileObject> al = new ArrayList<FileObject>();
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = s.nextLine();            
            al.add(new FileObject().createFileObject(line));
        }
        Collections.sort(al,new FileObjectComparator());

        for (FileObject i: al)
            System.out.println(i);

    }

}

class FileObject {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public FileObject createFileObject(String line) {
        if(line != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
            for(String str : line.split(",")) {
                str = str.trim();
                if(str.matches("([\\d]*)")) {
                    id = Integer.valueOf(str);
                } else {
                    name = str;
                }
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    ... // getters and setters
    @Override
    public String toString() {      
        return "[ID] "+id+ " [Name] "+name ;
    }
}

class FileObjectComparator implements Comparator<FileObject> {

    @Override
    public int compare(FileObject o1, FileObject o2) {      
        return o2.getId() - o1.getId();
    }

}
```